# iOS 10 push notifications - how does willPresentNotification and didReceiveNotificationResponse work?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

Currently I have my app set up to receive push notifications in ios 9 where it works perfectly but with iOS 10 I'm not receiving them. I've looked over various responses on stackoverflow and came across this:

[Push Notifications not being received on iOS 10, but working on iOS 9 and before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532953/push-notifications-not-being-received-on-ios-10-but-working-on-ios-9-and-before)

which appears to work for the poster.  I'm not entirely sure what code I'm supposed to add under the  willPresentNotification and didReceiveNotificationResponse sections.  If anyone has any examples of how these sections work it will be appreciated.  This is my relevant code for handling push notifications so far:

```
import UserNotifications
import Whisper

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  registerForPushNotifications(application)
}

 //MARK: Push Notification Settings
  func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

    //check to see if phone is updated to iOS 10
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
      UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
      UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
        if (granted)
        {
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
        else{
          print("registering for push notifications unsuccessful")
        }
      })
    }

    else{ //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using
      let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
        forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    }

  }

  //Notification handling for iOS 10
  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification - NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE

  }

  @available(iOS 10.0, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification -NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE
  }


  //This is called if user selects to receive push notifications
  func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    //    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    //    }
  }

  func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
      tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    //save device token to keychain
    self.deviceToken = tokenString
    userInfo.sharedInstance.savePushNotDeviceToken(tokenString)
    NSUserDefaultsManager.sharedManager.pushNotifications = true

    //register device token to api
    registerPushNotificationDevice(tokenString)

    print("Device Token:", tokenString)
  }


  func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to register:", error)

    //save push notifications state
    NSUserDefaultsManager.sharedManager.pushNotifications = false

  }


  //In- App push notifications
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == .Active {

      let navigationController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

      let alert = [String: String]()
      let title = ""
      let body = ""

      // Default printout of userInfo
      print("All of userInfo:\n\( userInfo)\n")

      if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
          if let title = alert["title"] as? NSString {
            if let body = alert["body"] as? NSString {

              let announcement = Announcement(title: title as String, subtitle: body as String, image: UIImage(named: "Image"))
                show(shout: announcement, to: navigationController)

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }



}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For remote and local notification in iOS 10 we have [UserNotifications.framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications).  To handle notification there are two delegate methods of **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** available in  UserNotifications.framework.  You need to do the same code you are doing in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method to get userInfo.
This two methods are available to handle userInfo according to your app requirements.

```
//UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate delegate methods to get userInfo

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
        print("\(userInfo)")

     }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        // Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
        print("\(userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! It took me forever to realize that userInfo is now buried under "notification.request.content"