# Getting Push Notification Successful for Old Device Token After Reinstalling the App using GCM

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have uninstalled my app and I reinstall that again, after that it is still getting push notification successful for old device token. I am not getting what should I do?

Comment: Have a look at my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532953/push-notifications-not-being-received-on-ios-10-but-working-on-ios-9-and-before/40757029#40757029

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall the app then its device token is same at the time of reinstall. That is the reason you are getting push notification again for same device. For that ask your server guy to delete that device token from server.