# GCM push is not received on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My app uses GCM to send push notifications and it all worked great.
Recently, one of subdcribers bought iPhone 7 and wrote to me, that push notifications dont work.

1. I've checked the logs from GCM - message is sent correctly:

{"multicast_id":6854913573879465744,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1484614306664165%6a57bb166a57bb16"}]}

2. She does receive other notifications from facebook, viber, etc., so no trouble with network.
3. Notifications are enabled in general and for my app.
4. "Do not disturb" is off.
5. Other subscribers with iOS 10.2 successfully receive notifications on their iPhones 5/6.
6. Reinstalling the app didnt help. App successfully receives the token, but doesnt receive notifications after.

What else can I check? Thank you.

Comment: Do you use `UNUserNotificationCenter` in your code?

Comment: No, I dont use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common issue on iPhone7. Check it [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7695017?start=0&tstart=0). I guess you have done all the workarounds in the link given but still no luck to fix the issue. Maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39618207/5832311) might help. Suggested action is to make sure that on your project settings, under the Capabilities Tab, scroll down to `Push Notifications` and turn it to `ON`. This automatically generates an entitlements file that contains the key `APS Environment`.