# Why aren't remote push notifications working on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I've looked at both [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532953/push-notifications-not-being-received-on-ios-10-but-working-on-ios-9-and-before), amongst many other similar questions and followed all of the steps; now my question is, what are other things that I can try to ensure that it isn't on my end? The back end developer i'm working with is adamant that everything is correct on his end. I've remade the certificates several times & sent him the respective .p12 files... I'm at a loss for what other things I can try.

prior to iOS 10, this used to be called when I registered, however it does not do that any longer. Is this only for iOS 9?

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings
```

Comment: Push notifications are notoriously flaky. However, are you using the [registration callback](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application)?

Comment: The [failure callback](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622962-application) might also give you clues.

Comment: @PedroCastilho unfortunately i have that set up and it isn't getting called either.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue when using Firebase notifications as well.

Comment: @Meshach were you able to resolve the problem? if so, how did you accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending notification using [this](http://pushtry.com) website using your p12/pem and UUID.

```
// For device token use this
func application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
        deviceToken: Data ) {

        let tokenString = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02X", $0) }.joined()
        print("Device Token:", tokenString)
}
```

Also, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532953/push-notifications-not-being-received-on-ios-10-but-working-on-ios-9-and-before) is really helpful. This would help you to find the bug if issue is from backend side or yours.

Comment: that website isn't even encrypted .... and the second link you sent me I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Jay Yeah that link is same and it worked for me, as an alternative you can also use this application https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12