# NSCFString 0x2749a0 valueForUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key push_type

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

**My Json**

```
{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = "This is a testing message !!!";
        title = Notification;
    };
};
data = "{\"push_type\":6,\"badge\":1,\"alert\":\"This is a testing message !!!\",\"sound\":\"default\",\"content-available\":\"1\",\"is_login\":2}";
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1494478903994917%6c350cc06c350cc0"; }
```

**I want to get push_type** like here it is 6.

**My code is:**

```
NSDictionary *data=[[userInfo valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"push_type"]];
```

After run this line an error occur push_type is not key value coding complaints...

Could you please help me where i am wrong,or how can i achieve this,please refer me an example,link thanks!

Comment: add "data" inside "alert", then try.

Comment: "data" is not Dictionary as per your Json, It is string so will not able to fetch "push_type" from it, that's why it shows  push_type is not key value coding complaints.

Comment: NSString *data=[[userInfo valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"push_type"]];

Answer (score 3):

Try with it.

```
NSString *jsonString=[[userInfo valueForKey:@"data"];

NSData *JsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

Now from "data" dictionary you can get any value from its key, like "push_type" etc...

Comment: dear patel i aleardy accept that...
could you guide me about one thing ..??
my push notification working fine on ios version <10 but now i have a device its version is 10.2,here only this device notification not received,what changes are required for ios 10,please refer an example or link...Thanks

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267549/ios-how-to-integrate-push-notification-in-ios-10

Comment: dear i already done that steps but still not receiving notification o ios 10